2x2 interaction plot when you only have summary statistics for each group
Thought someone here could give me some leads. I've been looking for a good example of a 2x2 interaction (i.e., cross-over) line plot, but all the examples I find assume you have participant-level data and are calculating the means or proportions you want to plot. I have many 2x2 tables of means and proportions that I want to plot (one for each table). Setting aside issues of multiple tests, having many plots to look at, etc., can anyone point me in the right direction? I've used ggplot2 for other kinds of plots, but I don't use it a lot. Didn't know if there was a package that's better for this now.
If a little more detail helps, my 2x2 table includes rows for mode (method of data collection), and columns for year, and I want to make a plot that looks like those here
See example table and plot from table linked below:
structure(list(...1 = c("Mode 1", "Mode 2"), 
    Year 1 = c(10, 40), Year 2 = c(20, 30)), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ), 
    row.names = c(NA, -2L))



It is much easier to help you if you supply some (example) data, e.g. using dput(your_df) end edit your question to include it.

Edited OP to add example of table and resulting plot that I did in Excel.

As @Axeman suggests, please include your data in a text format (e.g. using dput()), not as an image.

I think this is what you're looking for. Imported to R and then ran dput on it. Please excuse my ignorance. Newish to R. Thanks!:
structure(list(...1 = c("Mode 1", "Mode 2"), Year 1 = c(10,
40), Year 2 = c(20, 30)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L))

I hate to say it, but this is probably a question that ChatGPT or some other LLM could answer well ... the only tricky parts below are that (1) you have to convert your data to long format and (2) because your x-axis variable is categorical, you need to specify a group mapping explicitly.
df <- structure(list(`...1` = c("Mode 1", "Mode 2"), 
    `Year 1` = c(10, 40), `Year 2` = c(20, 30)), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ), 
    row.names = c(NA, -2L))

library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw()) ## cosmetic
## wide to long (and rename first column)
dfL <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -`...1`,
         names_to = "year") |>
    dplyr::rename(mode = "...1")
## plot
ggplot(dfL, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
   geom_line(aes(colour = mode, group = mode))

If you don't want the colours you don't have to specify that mapping.
Going some distance toward replicating the look of the linked plots:
theme_set(theme_classic())
ggplot(dfL, aes(year, value)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = mode)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape=mode, fill = mode), size = 4) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 22)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "black"))



Thanks so much Ben! And thanks for the ChatGPT reminder. Still trying to work that into my workflow. I need to take the same advice I give my staff. I've bookmarked this thread so I can share it with others as needed. I really appreciate the time help!

I'd clean up the data frame a bit:
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
    Mode = c("Mode 1", "Mode 2"), 
    `Year 1` = c(10, 40), 
    `Year 2` = c(20, 30)
    ) 
  

or
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Mode, ~`Year 1`, ~`Year 2`,
  "Mode 1", 10, 20,
  "Mode 2", 40, 30
)  

and then
df |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Mode, names_to = "Year", values_to = "Value") |>
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = Value, group = Mode, colour = Mode))


Thanks for the addition, Michiel! Helps me learn R. I really appreciate it.
